# Computing $E[\Theta^2]$ when knowing that $\Theta \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \tau^2)$

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Suppose $\Theta \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \tau^2)$. Then $E[\Theta] = 0$.

**Question:** With these assumptions, can one use Mathematica to compute $E[\Theta^2]$?

Comment: `Moment[NormalDistribution[0, \[Tau]^2], 2]`

Comment: Just to note:  *Mathematica* considers the second parameter to be the standard deviation rather than the variance.  Your use of $\tau^2$ suggests you might be characterizing the normal distribution using the precision (the reciprocal of the variance) rather than the variance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't my area of expertise, but I think you can do:

```
Expectation[θ^2, θ \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, τ^2]]
```

> τ^4

Comment: This works, and as a new user of Mathematica, this is simply astounding.

Comment: Given the OP's notation that say $X \sim N(0,s^2)$, the solution using Mma notation would be:  `Expectation[x^2, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, s]]`  which would yield the solution $s^2$, not $s^4$.